# Cordova build error - unable to find attribute android:font

Tags: android, cordova, build

I am using Cordova for building Android and iOS app, but when I run the build I get the following errors:

`ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontStyle
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontWeight`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools check the version of your latest build tools and use in appFolder\platforms\android\project.properties:

`cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:<your build tools version>`

Comment: It worked. I had just to downgrade the Android Support Version to 23.+

Answer (score 0):

try this in project.properties file.

```
target=android-26
```

Hope this help:)